# Echo command without spaces

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I am trying to output some variables but am getting unwanted spaces between the characters. For example, if variable 1 = 3 , variable 2 = 5 and variable 3 = 0.

When I run:

`echo %1%%2%%3%`

I should get "350", not "3 5 0 ". How can I get the "350" result instead of the result with spaces. Thanks

EDIT:
a section from my script (Please note the "set char"  is just for this example and is assigned from a variable in the actual script):

```
set char=3

if "%char%" == "1" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set c=1 & goto Character4
if "%char%" == "2" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set c=2 & goto Character4
if "%char%" == "3" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set c=3 & goto Character4
if "%char%" == "4" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set c=4 & goto Character4
if "%char%" == "5" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set c=5 & goto Character4
if "%char%" == "6" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set c=6 & goto Character4
if "%char%" == "7" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set c=7 & goto Character4
if "%char%" == "8" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set c=8 & goto Character4
if "%char%" == "9" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set c=9 & goto Character4
if "%char%" == "0" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set c=0 & goto Character4


:character4
set char=4

if "%char%" == "1" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set d=1 & goto check
if "%char%" == "2" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set d=2 & goto check
if "%char%" == "3" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set d=3 & goto check
if "%char%" == "4" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set d=4 & goto check
if "%char%" == "5" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set d=5 & goto check
if "%char%" == "6" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set d=6 & goto check
if "%char%" == "7" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set d=7 & goto check
if "%char%" == "8" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set d=8 & goto check
if "%char%" == "9" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set d=9 & goto check
if "%char%" == "0" echo %char% >> %userProfile%\test2.txt & set d=0 & goto check

:check
echo %c%%d%
```

This will return "3 4 " instead of "34"

Comment: Use quotes to avoid unwanted spaces in assignments: `& set "c=1" & goto ...` and don't insert spaces when you don't want them: `echo %char%>>`

Comment: lol, dont believe I missed that. Yep the semicolons did it Aacini. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the source of your problem, but you should use quotes in your SET statement to prevent accidental trailing whitespace - everything after the last quote is ignored when the leading quote is before the variable name:

```
set "var=value"  This text after last quote is ignored
```

You have the same unwanted space issue in your file output. Your problem is the unwanted space before `<<` and `&` - The space is included in the output. But you cannot simply remove the space, because then you have `3>...`, which means redirect file handle 3. The solution is to put the redirection at the front:

```
set "char=3"

if "%char%" == "1" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set c=1& goto Character4
if "%char%" == "2" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set c=2& goto Character4
if "%char%" == "3" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set c=3& goto Character4
if "%char%" == "4" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set c=4& goto Character4
if "%char%" == "5" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set c=5& goto Character4
if "%char%" == "6" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set c=6& goto Character4
if "%char%" == "7" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set c=7& goto Character4
if "%char%" == "8" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set c=8& goto Character4
if "%char%" == "9" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set c=9& goto Character4
if "%char%" == "0" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set c=0& goto Character4


:character4
set "char=4"

if "%char%" == "1" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set d=1& goto check
if "%char%" == "2" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set d=2& goto check
if "%char%" == "3" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set d=3& goto check
if "%char%" == "4" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set d=4& goto check
if "%char%" == "5" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set d=5& goto check
if "%char%" == "6" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set d=6& goto check
if "%char%" == "7" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set d=7& goto check
if "%char%" == "8" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set d=8& goto check
if "%char%" == "9" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set d=9& goto check
if "%char%" == "0" >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%& set d=0& goto check

:check
echo %c%%d%
```

But there is a much better way to do things :-)

You can use FOR /F to validate the character - if the character contains a non digit, then the FOR loop will fire, so the loop exits with success, so the error processing code after `||` will not fire. If the character contains only digits, then the loop does not fire, so it exits with error, and the error processing code executes. There is no longer any need for GOTO. The odd looking `(call )` is just an arcane syntax that does nothing except clear ERRORLEVEL (sets it to 0) - it is basically a no-op.

```
set "char=3"
(for /f "eol=1 delims=0123456789" %%C in ("%char%") do (call ))||>>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%&set "c=%char%"

set "char=4"
(for /f "eol=1 delims=0123456789" %%C in ("%char%") do (call ))||>>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%&set "d=%char%"

echo %c%%d%
```

I would write the code as follows - much easier to read:

```
set "char=3"
(for /f "eol=1 delims=0123456789" %%C in ("%char%") do (call )) || (
  >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%
  set "c=%char%"
)

set "char=4"
(for /f "eol=1 delims=0123456789" %%C in ("%char%") do (call )) || (
  >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%
  set "d=%char%"
)

echo %c%%d%
```

You can add additional code to handle invalid (non-digit) characters:

```
set "char=3"
(for /f "eol=1 delims=0123456789" %%C in ("%char%") do (call )) && (
  REM Handle invalid character here
) || (
  >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%
  set "c=%char%"
)

set "char=4"
(for /f "eol=1 delims=0123456789" %%C in ("%char%") do (call )) && (
  REM Handle invalid character here
) || (
  >>"%userProfile%\test2.txt" echo %char%
  set "d=%char%"
)

echo %c%%d%
```

Comment: Thanks dbenham. My issue was resolved by @Aacini, but your solution will definately help others who run into the same issue I had.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, the way to avoid spaces in assignments is enclosing the variable name and its value in quotes; and to avoid spaces in redirections, just don't insert any space before the `>>` characters. However, if the character before the `>>` is a digit then this method fail, because it is taken as a standard handle number, so in this case the redirection should be moved to the beginning of the command. These changes are included in the code below that get the same result of your original code, but in a much simpler way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize "digits" variable
set "digits=/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/0/"

set char=3

rem If when try to delete "/%char%/" from "digits" variable, it change...
if "!digits:/%char%/=!" neq "%digits%" (
   rem then "char" variable contain a digit
   >> %userProfile%\test2.txt echo %char%& set "c=%char%" & goto Character4
)

:character4
set char=4

if "!digits:/%char%/=!" neq "%digits%" (
   >> %userProfile%\test2.txt echo %char%& set "d=%char%" & goto check
)

:check
echo %c%%d%
```

Comment: Thanks Aacini, you did solve my issue with the quotes answer. Script is complete and working as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're assigning an arithmetic variable (e.g. 3), I recommend you to (e.g. `set /a variable 1=3`), this will remove spaces in front/behind the assigned value. Basically `set /a` and `set` doesn't make much diffreence in first-time assignment. But keep in mind, `set` is programmed to assign string variable, so spaces will be included.

Comment: The currently assigned value would be unknown and sourced from a text file. The script is scanning for for and returning only characters which are numbers. For example "12aed3d9" will only return "1239". I have edited my question a bit